# In react hooks the html section which is not intended to hide also gets hidden

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If the login user `privilege` is "ADMIN", then I am showing the `showNewsSection.show &&(..` and when a user with `PLAYER` privilege logged in, then that showNewsSection will not be displaying. This is fine.

But the problem here is, the `Recent News:` is also gets hidden for PLAYER, any reason why that is happening ?

note:  For ADMIN user, this section gets displayed.

```
  const [newDetails, setNewsDetails] = useState({ _id: '', newstitle: '', newsdetails: ''})
  const [displaynewsDetails, setShowNewsDetails] = useState([]);
  const [showNewsSection, setShowNewsSection] = useState({ show: false });
  const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');

  useEffect(()=>{
    displayNewsSection(privilege);
  },[]);

 const displayNewsSection = (privilege) => {
    if (privilege == "ADMIN") {
      setShowNewsSection({ show: true })
    } else {
      setShowNewsSection({ show: false })
    }
  }
```

If privilege is `ADMIN` then show below `NewsSection and Recent News:`

```
{
            showNewsSection.show && (
            <div className="layout">
              <span className="col col-main">
                <h3>Add news here ?</h3>
                <span className="specialAboutus_data_1">
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="myForm">
                    <div className="newsfillContentDiv formElement">
                      <label>
                        <input name="newstitle"  className="inputRequest formContentElement" type="text" placeholder="title" 
                        onChange={onChange}
                        minLength={4}
                        maxLength={50}
                        ref={register({
                          required: "News title is required !"
                        })}
                        />
                        <span className="newsErrorTextFormat">{errors.newstitle && errors.newstitle.message}</span>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <textarea name="newsdetails" className="inputRequest formContentElement" type="textarea"  placeholder="news details" 
                        onChange={onChange}
                        minLength={10}
                        maxLength={1200}
                        ref={register({
                          required: "News details is required !"
                        })}
                        />
                        <span className="newsErrorTextFormat">{errors.newsdetails && errors.newsdetails.message}</span>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="loginsubmitButtonDiv formElement" style={{ margin: isError ? '50px 0 20px 0' : '20px 0 20px 0' }}>
                        <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </span>
                <label>
                  <span className="newsValidationText">{helperText}</span>
                </label>
              </span> 
              <span className="col col-complementary">
              <h3>Successfull Message: </h3>
              <span className="joinAboutus_data_1">
                 {isSent ? thankYouMessage : form }
              </span>  
              </span>  
            </div>   
              )}




 <span className="col col-newsarea">
                <h3>Recent News:</h3>
                {
                displaynewsDetails.map(( {id, newstitle, newsdetails , createdAt} ) => (
                <span  key={id} className="newsPlace">
                  <span className="dateAndTimeDisplay" key={createdAt}><b>{moment(createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY, h:mm')}</b></span>
                  <b key={newstitle}>{newstitle}</b><br/><br/>
                  <span key={newsdetails}>{newsdetails}</span>
                </span>
                ))
                }
  </span>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-mountain-1pr05?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you create a sandbox for the same. Here it doesn't seems that you've placed any condition over the Recent news section. It should be displayed everytime.

Comment: Not enough evidence.

Comment: @Mohit, Thank mate, i find out the reason. in the server side I was looking based on `const newsdetails = await NewsModel.findAll({
       where: { email: userEmail },
       order: [
        [sequelize.literal('createdAt'), 'desc']
        ]
      });`

Comment: After removing the `where..{` it is working as expected

Comment: Added the codesandbox link